# Controlling stderr and stdout output in WildFly

Tags: logging, stderr, wildfly-8

In my application I got used to the following debug output: normally it prints a few lines per request to stderr, but logs a lot of information (via log4j) to a file. Typically, most important thing for me is the stderr output (that's why I want it concise), but when something doesn't work as expected, I can investigate the log, which can easily be thousands line per request.

Now that I'm migrating the application to WildFly, I found that the server pipes all stderr output through its logging system, so it looks like this:

```
14:06:15,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) ACTUAL-DEBUG-OUTPUT
```

and is additionally colored as an error. Also, stdout output seems to be redirected to /dev/null...

Can I somehow configure WildFly to just let stderr output go through as is, without adding useless (for me) noise and coloring? If possible, I'd like to do the same for stdout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, with some googling and hacking I got what I want:

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=JUST-PRINT:add(formatter="%s%E%n")
/subsystem=logging/logger=stderr:add(use-parent-handlers="false", handlers=[JUST-PRINT])
/subsystem=logging/logger=stdout:add(use-parent-handlers="false", handlers=[JUST-PRINT])
```

Comment: Did it really remove stderr messages from your log system? I would like to do the same, but I'm using Thorntail (wildfly for microservices). Do you how to set a Thorntail's yaml configuration file to make it work?